# In VS Code's integrated terminal, how can I click paths with spaces in them to open the file in an editor tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2QT8.png)So this is probably an easy fix for most but I haven't found anything online on fixing this.

Most people when using the terminal on Visual Source code and come up against an error they can cmd/ctrl click on the file pathway and navigate straight to the line/code of the issue.

I can no longer do this, instead when I cmd click (I'm on macOS) I get a global search for the file instead.

I don't want this. I prefer to navigate to the link straight from the terminal as most people can.

I want to be able to navigate to the selected file/code using cmd click in the terminal.

Comment: can you show a screenshot of what you're seeing? Is the path to a file in the currently opened workspace folder? or is it to a file outside of the currently opened workspace folder?

Comment: I've gone ahead and added a link to the screen shot of whats happening when trying to cmd click in vs code terminal

Links in the top of issue text (didnt give it a name)

Answer (score 1):

You could try fiddling with the `terminal.integrated.wordSeparators` setting. Its description reads:

> A string containing all characters to be considered word separators when double-clicking to select word and in the fallback 'word' link detection. Since this is used for link detection, including characters such as `:` that are used when detecting links will cause the line and column part of links like `file:10:5` to be ignored.

The default value of the setting is  `()[]{}',\"`─‘’|`(notice that it includes a space). Removing the space might help, but only if the format of the link has delimiters that you can put in`terminal.integrated.wordSeparators`.

---

Googling "`github vscode issues terminal link space click`", I found the following: [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/155532#issuecomment-1226441356), which leads to [Support path links that contain spaces in the integrated terminal #97941](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97941). A specific set of cases were made to be handled by the changes there. Quoting [this comment by @tyriar](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97941#issuecomment-1362225547):

> I put this together in [#169786](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/169786), here are the detected formats when it gets merged:
>
> - Python style links: `From "<path>", line <line>`
> - Lines that only contain a path: `<path>`
> - C++ compiler(?) style errors: `<path>(<line>,<col>) :<...>`
> - Independently styled file paths: `foo<underlined_path>bar`
>
> I think that should cover the main cases called out in the issue, let me know if your case isn't covered by this.

VS Code 1.88 added another case for patterns like `FILE: path:line:column`, that works even if the path part has spaces (see [release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_88#_new-link-formats)).

It looks like your case isn't handled. You can [create a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) asking for it to be handled. If you do so, please provide sufficient information in your issue ticket to describe the format that you would like to be supported, and comment here with a link to your issue ticket, or edit the link into this answer post.

If you really want to workaround the problem right now, you can rename your directories and files in that path to not have spaces in their names.

Historic notes: Other possibly related issue tickets include [#159676](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/159676), [#159677](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/159677), and [#159696](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/159696).

[Other formats have also been added in VS Code 1.80](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_80#_multiline-and-range-link-formats).

Comment: sorry im fairly new to this stuff and the way i followed my errors was via clicking the respective file in the terminal showing where the error was. 

can you elaborate a bit more??

Comment: @luckyvb TL;DR your case is not handled by VS Code at the current time. You can work around the problem by changing your directories and files in that path to not have spaces in their names.

Comment: Before i was able to use cmd click to follow links/file pathways abt a week or 2 ago but then it stopped working overnight.

Comment: @luckyvb then you should consider reporting it as a bug. Use the `Help: Report Issue...` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). If you do, please comment here with a link to your GitHub issue ticket once it is created.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/184316