# How to make option + click on mac in vscode integrated terminal work with elixir stack traces

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, elixir

Elixir has stack traces like this:

```
     stacktrace:
       (ecto 3.10.2) lib/ecto/queryable.ex:40: Ecto.Queryable.Atom.to_query/1
       (ecto 3.10.2) lib/ecto/query/builder/from.ex:155: Ecto.Query.Builder.From.apply/5
       (jump 0.1.0) lib/jump/integration_references/schema.ex:41: Jump.IntegrationReference.permissions_query/2
       (jump 0.1.0) lib/jump/users/permissions.ex:71: Jump.Permissions.permissions_query_for_resource/2
       (jump 0.1.0) lib/jump/users/permissions.ex:81: Jump.Permissions.permissions/2
       (jump 0.1.0) lib/jump/users/permissions.ex:38: anonymous fn/3 in Jump.Permissions.map/2
       (elixir 1.15.0) lib/enum.ex:2510: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
       (jump 0.1.0) lib/jump/users/permissions.ex:34: Jump.Permissions.map/2
       (jump 0.1.0) lib/jump_web/middleware/check_authorized.ex:17: Jump.Middleware.CheckAuthorized.call/2
       (absinthe 1.7.4) lib/absinthe/phase/document/execution/resolution.ex:234: Absinthe.Phase.Document.Execution.Resolution.reduce_resolution/1
       (absinthe 1.7.4) lib/absinthe/phase/document/execution/resolution.ex:189: Absinthe.Phase.Document.Execution.Resolution.do_resolve_field/3
       (absinthe 1.7.4) lib/absinthe/phase/document/execution/resolution.ex:174: Absinthe.Phase.Document.Execution.Resolution.do_resolve_fields/6
       (absinthe 1.7.4) lib/absinthe/phase/document/execution/resolution.ex:145: Absinthe.Phase.Document.Execution.Resolution.resolve_fields/4
       (absinthe 1.7.4) lib/absinthe/phase/document/execution/resolution.ex:88: Absinthe.Phase.Document.Execution.Resolution.walk_result/5
       (absinthe 1.7.4) lib/absinthe/phase/document/execution/resolution.ex:67: Absinthe.Phase.Document.Execution.Resolution.perform_resolution/3
       (absinthe 1.7.4) lib/absinthe/phase/document/execution/resolution.ex:24: Absinthe.Phase.Document.Execution.Resolution.resolve_current/3
       (absinthe 1.7.4) lib/absinthe/pipeline.ex:408: Absinthe.Pipeline.run_phase/3
       (absinthe_plug 1.5.8) lib/absinthe/plug.ex:536: Absinthe.Plug.run_query/4
       (absinthe_plug 1.5.8) lib/absinthe/plug.ex:290: Absinthe.Plug.call/2
       (phoenix 1.7.7) lib/phoenix/router/route.ex:42: Phoenix.Router.Route.call/2
```

But when I try to option click to jump to the file it includes the parentheses so it doesn't work. [image]

Anyone have any suggestions for fixing this?

I tried playing with

```
"terminal.integrated.wordSeparators": " ()[]{}',\"`─‘’|",
```

but can't figure out anything that works.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour with a `echo '(jump 0.1.0) test.md:2:'` (I created a test.md file with two lines in my workspace folder) and ctrl+clicking it (I'm on Ubuntu so I use ctrl+click). What happens for you if you try what I tried? Also, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76403777/11107541 and see if it effectively addresses your question.

Comment: dang it, that would imply that is a valid file path, so the only way to fix this is to convince elixir to change how they output stacktraces

Comment: what you did worked for me. Try this: `echo '(jump 0.1.0) lib/jump/integration_references/schema.ex:41'`

Comment: VS Code integrated terminal uses xterm.js. Can you try piping the output of whatever command is producing that error to see if it is uses OSC 8 hyperlinks? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64759060/11107541 Not sure if that will work, because some commandline tools are smart enough to not do fancy terminal things if they see they aren't piping to a terminal using something like `isatty`.

Comment: another test: try piping the command output containing that stack trace into a file, then print the file in the terminal, and see what behaviour you get.